# how I can get data from api url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to fetch data from Api url in my wordpress website, I find this function: wp_remote_get() 
to parse JSON from remote APIs

functions.php:

```
<?php
$request = wp_remote_get( 'my link' );
if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
    return false; // Bail early
}
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
$data = json_decode( $body );
if( ! empty( $data ) ) {

  print_r($data);
}
```

but it didn't return any data.

Comment: What did it return instead? Did you do any error logging? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and improve your question!

Comment: it's return nothing

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to write `json_decode($data)`.

In wordpress I have tried below link its work for me.

```
$request = wp_remote_get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Mexico&sensor=true&location=23.634501,-102.55278399999997&radius=10000&key=XXXXXXXXXXXX');
if( ! empty( $request ) ) {
   print_r($request);
}
```

Comment: it returns an error: WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [http_request_failed] => Array ( [0] => cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 5004 milliseconds ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )

Comment: May be issue in your url, please try below example its working.
`$request = wp_remote_get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', array( 'timeout' => 120, 'httpversion' => '1.1' ));
 if( ! empty( $request ) ) {
 $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
 $data = json_decode( $body );

 print_r($data);
}` @user6162695

Comment: (tabibbaghdad.net/v1/user_master/search_doctor)  this link is working for me. Are you working on server or local ?? @user6162695

Comment: I'm working on server

Comment: @user6162695 In local its working. so please increase allocated memory in server.

Comment: Ok, l will do that ... thanks very much